# Selenium not performing certain actions

Tags: selenium, error-handling

There is this website that I keep visiting every day to look for updates, but I started getting bored of visiting it just to find nothing. So I thought it could be a good idea to automate this task and whenever there are updates I'll get a message to my email. So I thought I could use Selenium and some other commands, but when I was coding, I stumbled upon a problem. I wanted selenium to click a button but it gave me the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

I've tried finding the button with different options. I've tried finding it by xpath, by name, by id, by class but nothing seems to work. I have read some threads on here and tried to resolve the issue with their advice but it didn't work either. I gave every action a few seconds(10 seconds to be exact) to be performed, but it still doesn't work. Maybe the website I chose to monitor doesn't allow it? Is it possible for them to block the actions I want to perform or is there maybe something I'm missing in the code?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide the html or url of the page?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but here is the HTML: <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Alla" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;" aria-invalid="false"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">Alla</span> <b class="caret"></b></button>